# Encontrar números insertados comunes en un rango. Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.4

Intento hacer un código que encuentre "huecos" en una lista de números en un rango de 0 a 24. Por ejemplo, si `l1 = [9, 5, 14]` y `l2 = [10, 8, 23]`, entonces hay "huecos" entre 0 y 4, entre 6 y 7, entre 11 y 14, entre 15 y 22 y entre 24 y 0 (algo cíclico).

Estoy experimentado con:

```
>>> l1 = [9, 12, 5]
>>> l2 = [9, 12, 4]
>>> for char in (l1 and l2):
    if l1 == l2:
        print(char)
```

Pero obtengo un error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<pyshell#33>", line 2, in 
> if l1[char] == l2[char]:
> IndexError: list index out of range

¿Qué me recomiendan?

Comment: ¿Por qué no unir ambas listas para hacer la búsqueda? ¿Es relevante que sean listas separadas? ¿Pueden ser tres, cuatro o más listas?

Comment: Las listas son separadas porque son usuarios diferentes. Sí se pueden crear más listas.

Answer (score 0):

Esta no es una respuesta.

Algunos problemas con el código (uso la versión que corresponde al error, no la que publicaste)

```
l1 = [9, 12, 5]
l2 = [9, 12, 4]
for char in (l1 and l2):
    if l1[char] == l2[char]:
        print(char)
```

Primero, el operador `and` aplicado entre listas devuelve la primera lista si ésta no es una lista vacía. Si es una lista vacía, devuelve la segunda lista. Una o la otra, no ambas, ni una mezcla.

Entonces, `(l1 and l2)` siempre va a retornar `l1` ...

Segundo, el `for char` significa que la variable `char` tomara los elementos de `l1`, esto es, tomara sucesivamente los valores 9, 12 y 14. El error es que usas ese valor para indexar el arreglo, lo que no tiene ninguna lógica y te produce el error mencionado, ya que `l1[9]` no existe.

Tampoco está claro cual es el resultado deseado, así que hasta aquí no más llego.

Answer (score 0):

Como bien te explicó Candid Moe, tienes errores que escapan del problema como tal.

Habiéndolos tomando en consideración, pudieses hacer algo como lo siguiente para solucionar tu problema

```py
from itertools import chain


LIST_TO_CHECK_AGAINST_ZERO = [-1]
l1 = [9, 5, 14]
l2 = [10, 8, 23]

l3 = sorted(chain(LIST_TO_CHECK_AGAINST_ZERO, l1, l2))
pairs_of_elements = zip(l3, l3[1:])
holes = [
    (current + 1, next_ - 1)
    for current, next_ in pairs_of_elements
    if difference_is_greater_than_one(current, next_)
]
```

En donde la función predicado `difference_is_greater_than_one()` puede ser así:

```
def difference_is_greater_than_one(current, next_):
    return (next_ - current) > 1
```

Con todo esto obtendrás dentro de `holes`:

```
[(0, 4), (6, 7), (11, 13), (15, 22)]
```

Esta solución te permite añadir cualquier número de listas para encontrar *huecos*. Solo añade la lista `ln` a la función `chain()`.

---

Referencias:

- [Función zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
- [Función itertools.chain()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)
- [Comprehensión de listas](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: En la parte `holes = [(current + 1, next_ - 1)]`, ahí `current` aún no está definido, de igual modo con `next_`. Tengo dudas en eso.

Comment: Sí está definido. Esas variables son declaradas en el `for` que conforma la comprehensión de lista. Pruébalo y verás que sí lo están.

Comment: ¿por qué están definidos antes del `for`?

Comment: Aunque lo parezca, técnicamente esas variables no están definidas antes que el `for`. La sintaxis de la comprehensión de listas establece que la la expresión (en tu caso: `(current + 1, next_ - 1)`) será evaluada en el contexto del `for` definido dentro de la comprehensión. Te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo a la documentación de la comprehensión de listas. Te dejé el link en las referencias de mi respuesta